# Elegant solution to running a classes initialization function after the variables in an instance of the class have been set

Tags: c#, function, class, initialization

I have this simple class which includes a string value (*s*) and an initialization function which writes the value. *s* is set to a default value.

```
class ExampleClass
{
     public string s = "default";
     public ExampleClass()
     {
           Console.Write(s);
     }  
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
           ExampleClass MyClass = new ExampleClass{ s = "MyString" };
     }
}
```

When run, an instance of the class is made with a custom string ("MyString"). When this new instance is made, the initialization function is called upon and run. The problem is, the initialization function is run before the value *s* is set, and therefore the function runs using the default function for s ("default").

Is there an elegant way to run an initialization function with the values set from new instance of a class?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing your Console.Write(s) inside your constructor - ExampleClass. The constructor is getting called the second you initialize your class ExampleClass. So yes, it will always write "default" instead of the "MyString"

You need to have another function that does Console.Write. Like this

`public void PrintString(){ Console.Write(s); }`

Then in your main function just do:

```
MyClass.PrintString();
```

One suggested change - not sure if this is elegant or not but it might be considered good practice is to not have public parameters in a class. Perhaps this -

```
class ExampleClass 
{
   public ExampleClass(string s = "default")
   {
       Console.Write(s);
   }
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       ExampleClass MyClass = new ExampleClass("MyString");
   }
}
```